# How can I align scale with axis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default, the scale for the x-axis and y-axis are on the bottom & left of the chart, respectively. I want them adjacent to the plot lines (the x- and y-axis). Here's an illustration of what I'm hoping to achieve: imgur.com/a/tf53t

I know that I can use `offset:` to move the scales to a specific pixel location, but they no longer align to the plot lines if I change the maximum/minimum values on either axis.

I labeled where I think offset should go in the code below, but I'm not sure what to type after it.

http://jsfiddle.net/z7eyv/60/

Here's the specific part of the code in question:

```
yAxis: {
min: -20,
  max: 20,
  tickInterval: 1,
    endOnTick: false,

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0.1,
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'}]
},
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false,
                    halo: {
                        size: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
  xAxis: {
  min: -20,
  max: 14,
  tickInterval: 1,
   gridLineWidth: 1,
    endOnTick: false,
    offset: //???????????????????????????????????????
    title: {
        text: '', 

    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0.1,
        width: 1,
        color: 'black'}]
},
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of what result are you expecting

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'align with the plotlines'?

Comment: Yes, no problem: http://imgur.com/j8mL5fh           I want the scale to align with the central x-axis and y-axis rather than the left and bottom margins, respectively. I don't want to just offset the scale with a pixel number, because I want the scale to align with the central axis even if I change the max/min x- or y-values.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the axis and axis labels to be at 0 on each axes?

Comment: I tried to make the illustration clearer: http://imgur.com/a/tf53t I want the #s to be adjacent to the x-axis and y-axis rather than in the left and bottom margins.